# Insert an array in a database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress page where i got a option list filled with an array. Code below:

```
$option = array("Zomervakantie", "Goede vrijdag", "Vrijdag na HV", "Bijzonder verlof", "Medisch", "Leeftijdsuren", "Bapo-uren", "EHBO-uren", "Compensatieverlof",
"3 en 4e paasdag", "Meivakantie", "Herfstvakantie");

    echo "Selecteer hier je type verlof: ";
    echo "<br />" . "<br />";
    echo "<select id='selectList' name='selectList'>";
        foreach ( $option as $list )
        {
            echo "<option value='" . $list . "'>" . $list . "</option>";
        } 
    echo "</select>";
```

When i'm trying to insert this the whole query doesn't work anymore.
This is a part of my query:   
                                                                  `$wpdb->insert('table',array(column=>$_POST['selectList']));`
I'm using a wordpress query.

 Anyone knows what the correct way to insert this in a database? i'm using phpmyadmin.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your form method (GET or POST)?

Comment: You try to POST without a form, how should that work?

Comment: My form method is POST

Comment: I got a form ofcourse!!

Comment: My whole query works only when I add the lines from this query to my existing query it doesn't insert anymore!

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge of wordpress is very limited.

However, this appears to be invalid PHP to me (unless 'column' is a wordpress constant):

```
$wpdb->insert('table',array(column=>$_POST['selectList']));
```

Try

```
$wpdb->insert('table',array('column'=>$_POST['selectList']));
```

If you don't already, you should get an IDE which points out syntax errors as you type, such as Netbeans or PHPStorm. I assume Eclipse also does this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my query just works fine, only when i try to insert my option list the query stops working. And i'm using Eclipse:)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a array directly to database just use these code

```
$option = array("Zomervakantie", "Goede vrijdag", "Vrijdag na HV", "Bijzonder verlof", "Medisch", "Leeftijdsuren", "Bapo-uren", "EHBO-uren", "Compensatieverlof",
"3 en 4e paasdag", "Meivakantie", "Herfstvakantie");
$wpdb->insert('table',$option);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store an array in a database, you can serialize it, or encode it in JSON (there is a PHP function for JSON encoding). It becomes a String, which you can store easily.

It works with objects too.

Example :

```
$array = array("1" => "PHP code tester Sandbox Online",  
          "foo" => "bar", 5 , 5 => 89009, 
          "case" => "Random Stuff",
          "PHP Version" => phpversion()
          );



$string = json_encode ($array);

echo($string);
echo "\n";

$array2 = json_decode($string);

foreach( $array2 as $key => $value ){
    echo $key."\t=>\t".$value."\n";
}
```

Comment: I've never used JSON do you have an example for me so I can take a look at it?